# Ajax POST request not valid

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to get BlackBerry PIN on this page: http://m.tokobagus.com/iklan/drees-import-51336153.html/?&opt=2&int=1&pg=1&catid=230&subcatid=230

It sends an Ajax POST request to this URL: `http://m.tokobagus.com/search/ajaxbb`

their script is:

```
$.post(url,{pin:$("#advscrw").val()},function(k){k=$.parseJSON(k)});
```

success result: {"status":1,"data":"xxxxxxx"}

`pin` is the only parameter, and its value is `N0Q2MzY2MUQ=`. But when testing the request using PHP, the results is {"status":0,"data":null}

```
    $options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'content' => http_build_query($data),
    ),
);
$context  = stream_context_create($options);
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

var_dump($result);
```

What's wrong?

Comment: If the statuscode is `0` there is a problem with the connection. Either the request timed out or one party forcefully closed the connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It only responds with the actual data if it sees the `X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest` request header.

```
'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n" .
             "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest\r\n",
```

Comment: thank you! i had try using `poster` firefox plugin and set `XMLHttpRequest` but still get null result.
use php it's working :)